# How to remove business process flow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, business-process

Accordint to [this blog](http://mscrmonline.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/crm-2013-how-to-remove-business-process-flow/) one can hide the business process flows. I'm trying to follow it but there's no flows defined for my opportunity (according to the list).

I'd like to "delete" the flow for Opportunity entity (or at least affect it somehow to display different steps/different number of steps). The reason is that we'll be migrating from an older version and they've got a picklist with percentages of the deal being done. Not sure how to map it onto the Opportunity in 2013 and even if, I'm not sure the client'd like it.

Is it at all possible to remove business process flow from Opportunity in CRM 2013?

When I do follow the guide and fool around with **all flows**, I get to remove the one for **Opportunity** but then I'm shown the error message as in the image below. So I'm assuming that it's not the correct approach. Or did the blogger referred to in the first paragraph cheat and took his screenshot **after** closing the warning?   :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The blogger in the blog is using the earlier version of Dynamics CRM than yours. Newer versions of Dynamics CRM will show the above warning.

Beside one way in the blog, there are a couple of way to show/hide Business Process Flow:

1. use Javascript to set the display attribute of process bar element:

   ```
   function hideBusinessProcessFlow()
   {
    document.getElementById('header_process_d').style.display = "none";
   }

   function showBusinessProcessFlow()
   {
     document.getElementById('header_process_d').style.display = "block";
   }
   ```

Reference: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/misscrm360exploration/archive/2014/07/24/show-and-hide-business-process-flow-in-crm-2011-2013.aspx

Please note that this is unsupported customization.

2. Update `processid` and `stageid` fields of the record. Use update these fields with Javascript or writing a plugin/workflow to do this.

Have a look at this solution: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Change-Dynamics-CRM-2013-a6beb85e

In your case, you just need to update `processid` and `stageid` fields to `null`, then the annoying warning will disappear.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the complete list of Processes under Customisations?  If you're looking at an unmanaged solution it won't appear unless it's been added to that solution.  It's in there OOB and called `Opportunity Sales Process`, I just deactivated it on a clean org.  No need to delete it, just deactivate it or edit as required.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that can be done for any business process flow in MS CRM:

1. Deactivate BPF
2. Delete BPF

In order to remove Business Process Flow (BPF) from existing records, it is not enough to just deactivate BPF. Even when we deactivate BPF, records that are associated with it will still show BPF with warning message that it is deactivated.

It is true, if you delete BPF from Processes in MS Dynamics CRM, they will be removed (not showed) from the records that were associated with that BPF. However, what if you do not want to delete default BPFs, like those related to sales process on system entities (Leads, Opportunities and Accounts)? What if you want to hide these default system BPF from default system entity (i.e. Opportunity)?

In this case you need to write plugin/workflow activity to remove association of the entity record from BPF.

See my [GitHub example](https://github.com/ZeKoU/BPFRemoveWorkflowActivity/blob/master/BPFRemoveWorkflowActivity/BPFRemoveWorkflowActivity.cs) how to do this

This MS CRM community post is also useful: 
[Remove business Process Flow from Account](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/155044)